# How to make MySQL MATCH...AGAINST use various word separators?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table with 300K string values. These values contain all types of word separators so it looks like this:

```
id  value
1   A B C
2   A B_C
3   A_B-C
4   A-B-C
```

Let's say I want to find all four rows containing `A` and `B`. This query
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(value) AGAINST('+A +B' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`
will return only one row with space separated values:
`1   A B C`

Is there a way to make `MATCH...AGAINST` use other word separators? I tried to use `LIKE` and it was too slow.

Comment: Do you try to search in value and you need to find all matching records ?

Comment: There are three ways described in the docs. "Suppose that you want to treat the hyphen character ('-') as a word character. Use one of these methods: .." - Read [more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-modify-character-set). But I'm afraid you will not like any of the "solutions".

Comment: Thank you, @PaulSpiegel. You're right - these solutions are overkill for this task. But, at least, now I know that there's not easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to alter your app and schema just a little bit to solve this problem. You have two tasks:

## Task 1: Transform your existing data

Assuming you need to keep the source data unchanged:

Step 1: Add a field to your schema, "searchFriendly", same datatype as the source data.

Step 2: Write a script to transform the data you already have. Get the whole data set and do string replaces to get spaces.

Step 3: Save that transformed data to the new searchFriendly field.

## Task 2: Modify the app so that all future database save/update's on this data, also perform the transformation and save that data as well.

Step 1: Find the part of the app that saves these records.

Step 2: Before actually writing the data to the database, perform the transformation.

Step 3: Add the transformed data to your API call to save/update the record, under the searchFriendly field.